# extra dependencies listed for urdf_tutorials?

Tags: ros, urdf-tutorial, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While listing out the dependencies of the package urdf_tutorials using `sudo apt-cache depends ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorials`, I am obtaining the list :

```
  Depends: ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher
  Depends: ros-kinetic-pr2-description
  Depends: ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher
  Depends: ros-kinetic-rviz
  Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf
  Depends: ros-kinetic-xacro
```

However, when I refer to the documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/urdf_tutorial), there are more dependencies listed. So, why aren't these extra ones displayed with `sudo apt-cache depends`. Also, cross checking with the package.xml file, I have noticed that this command is displaying only the runtime dependencies of a package. Is it the case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255852/extra-dependencies-listed-for-urdf_tutorials?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current release of `urdf_tutorial` is [0.2.4](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=urdf_tutorial)

0.2.4 was released [April 2015](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/releases)

Many of those extra dependencies came in [June 2015](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/commit/f2db517470448e76ff3e7b541a54aedc01ab2a6a).

So, all that is to say, we're due for a new release.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0